# How can I download a video that are in screencast.com?

Tags: firefox, flash, google-chrome, video-streaming, download-manager

What Chrome or Firefox plugin can help me to download a video published at screencast.com. Pls, if you know another method to grab the video and the sound, let me know too ;)

Comment: This is a rather off topic question, but have a look [here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/search/?q=flash+capture&appver=17.0&platform=linux)

Comment: Thanks @iSeth, I tried some plugins and nothing, that is why I ask here, but the first one in your search works ;) Thanks again.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this Firefox Addon [Here](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/video-downloadhelper/?src=hp-dl-mostpopular)

It's called VideoDownloadHelper.

Comment: I try with [VideoDownloadHelper](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/video-downloadhelper/?src=hp-dl-mostpopular) and with  [Ant Video Downloader](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/video-downloader-player/) and nothing. [Flash Video Downloader](https://addons.mozilla.org/en-US/firefox/addon/flash-video-downloader-youtube/) work after check the "Enable .swf Files" option. Thanks All.

Answer (score 0):

I think, **FlareGet** would be an ideal choice for you as

> FlareGet is a full featured, multi-threaded and multi-segment download manager and accelerator

[FlareGet](http://apt.ubuntu.com/p/flareget)

But the free version in Ubuntu software center does not support "Browser integration", you need to pay $10 to get browser integration plugin. I guess without browser integration, download manager won't make sense.

So here is the workaround to get Browser integration for Firefox. I have tested it on Firefox 18 and it works like a charm.

> - Just go to Firefox > Tools > Add ons > Extensions.
> - Search for addon "**FlashGot**", install it and Restart the Firefox.
> - Go to Tools > Add ons > Extension > Preferences for FlashGot.
> - On **General** tab, choose FlareGet as download manager and check the check-box against "Show in Context Menu"
> - On **FlashGot Media** tab, choose FlareGet as download manager and check the check-box against "Show Toolbar button".
> - Now restart the Firefox. FlashGot will act as Firefox integration plugin for FlareGet.

Just right click any downloadable link and choose FlareGet.

> If you want you download video from YouTube just play the video, an icon will appear on right most side of the tile bar. Just click on that icon and FlareGet will capture and download the video.

I love Firefox so this is enough for me. Something similar can be worked out for Chrome.